# Is there any difference between those instructions?

Tags: swift

I have a function that converts an `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>`to `[T]` like that :

```
func convert<T>(pointer:UnsafeMutablePointer<T>, count:Int) -> [T] {
    let buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: pointer, count: count)
    return Array(buffer)
}
```

If I have :

```
var pointArray:UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint> // A 10 element array
```

Is there any difference between doing :

```
convert(pointArray, count:10)[0]
```

Or

```
pointArray[0]
```

I believe no one is safer than the other, and that actually, for what I am doing, the second approach is more efficient (and simpler, of course).

Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is safer, you're still fundamentally accessing a memory address unsafely, with no compiler protection.

Take care however, as you still have to manually release `pointArray` after using `convert`

Comment: Didn't thought I needed to do that in Swift, thank you ! How to release it ?

Comment: And the second one is faster right ? No need to release anything either for the second line ?

Comment: You have to manually release the memory in both cases. That's one of the things that makes UNSAFEMutablePointers unsafe: you've waived the ability to have ARC automatically manage your memory. You release them with [`UnsafeMutablePointer.dealloc()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_UnsafeMutablePointer_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structm/UnsafeMutablePointer/s:FSp7deallocFSiT_)

Comment: The second way would be faster, but negligibly so. The important question here is: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, I am making a wrapper around CGPath and I want to extract all points of the CGPath, making me work with pointers. But actually, what I really want to do is to understand better how pointers work in Swift, so I only need to call dealloc, nothing else to call directly on `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` ?

Comment: Nope, UnsafeMutableBufferPointer doesn't concern itself with the lifecycle of the memory it represents. But keep in mind, once you free `pointArray`, you can't use your UnsafeMutableBufferPointer anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and advices, it helps a lot ! I hadn't realised that I needed to release anything, so I would have probably ended wondering why memory usage was getting higher and higher for no reason.